# How to create a script that sets Particle Boid brain rules in Blender 4.0?

Tags: python, scripting, particles, add-on

I am trying to update an add-on called Spyderfy for Blender 4.0. It's a simple script that essentially does two things within its script.

1.) Imports 3d Insect models from a directory.
2.) Creates a Boid Particle system with those Insects instanced.

The problem is I am getting errors in the part of the script that adds the BOID Brain rules in the specific order I want. **This first part of the script works. Until the break in the code I mention below.**

```
 #NOW WE DO OUR BOID PARTICLE SYSTEM AND SETTINGS BELOW!
    
    #First we need too add a plane to our scene to use as the source of our particle system
    #add plane command
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=.35, enter_editmode=False, location=(bpy.context.scene.cursor.location))
    #rename plane command for selected objects below
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        obj.name = "Bug System"
    
    
    #Now we need to make the bug system we just appended the "Active object" so that we can adjust its particle settings afterwards
    #bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['BugParticles']
    
    #Now we adjust our newly appended particle system with custom particle system settings for the boids system below(from article on stackexchange)
   
    obj = bpy.context.active_object

    if len(obj.particle_systems) == 0:
        obj.modifiers.new("part", type='PARTICLE_SYSTEM')
        part = obj.particle_systems[0]

        settings = part.settings
        settings.name = 'Bug System'
        settings.count = context.scene.spyderfy_tool.bugs_amount
        settings.frame_start = 1
        settings.frame_end = (250)
        settings.lifetime = 500
        settings.lifetime_random = 0
        settings.emit_from = 'FACE'
        settings.physics_type = 'BOIDS'
        bpy.context.object.show_instancer_for_render = False
        settings.show_unborn = True
        settings.use_dead = True
        settings.render_type = 'COLLECTION'
        settings.particle_size = 1.00
        settings.size_random = 0.3
        bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].instance_collection = bpy.data.collections[context.scene.spyderfy_tool.my_stringbugsystem]
        settings.show_unborn = False
        settings.use_dead = False
        settings.use_scale_instance = True
        settings.jitter_factor = 0
        settings.object_factor = 1
        settings.effector_weights.turbulence = 0
        bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.land_ave_max = 1
        bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.bank = 0
        bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.pitch = 1
        bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.height = 0.04
        bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.use_land = True
        bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.use_climb = True
        
        #Only make bug system fly if only flying creatures but no crawling creatures are selected by the user
        if (context.scene.spyderfy_tool.my_boolwidow or context.scene.spyderfy_tool.my_boolbirdeating or 
        context.scene.spyderfy_tool.my_boolbeetle or context.scene.spyderfy_tool.my_boolcentipede or 
        context.scene.spyderfy_tool.my_boolcockroach or context.scene.spyderfy_tool.my_boolant == True):
            bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.use_flight = False
            
        else:
            #Make the boid system fly below
            bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.use_flight = True  
            #also make the air speed faster than default if only flying creatures selected
            bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.air_speed_max = 50
            #Don't let the boid system land
            bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.use_land = False
            #Don't let the boid system climb
            bpy.data.particles["Bug System"].boids.use_climb = False
```

**This is where I start getting Errors:**

```
        #adding BOID BRAIN RULES in correct order(help from stack exchange users lemon and batfinger)
        # Copy the current context
        context_override = bpy.context.copy()
        # Override the wanted property
        context_override["particle_settings"] = settings
        # Call the operators
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_del(context_override)
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_del(context_override)
        #continue with boid brain settings in correct order with override  
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_add(context_override, type='SEPARATE')
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_add(context_override, type='GOAL')
        #add goal object to goal brain setting below
        state = settings.boids.active_boid_state
        if (context.scene.spyderfy_tool.my_goalobject == True):
            state.active_boid_rule.object = bpy.data.objects['bugsystemgoal']
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_add(context_override, type='FLOCK')
```

The objective is to give the particle system three rules: Separate, Goal, and Flock. The Goal rule points to an empty that has been added to the scene with the script earlier. Any help or explanation is greatly appreciated.

Brad

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you'll have to change like this:

```
        #adding BOID BRAIN RULES in correct order(help from stack exchange users lemon and batfinger)
    # Copy the current context
    context_override = bpy.context.copy()
    # Override the wanted property
    context_override["particle_settings"] = settings
    with context.temp_override(**context_override):
        # Call the operators
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_del()
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_del()
        #continue with boid brain settings in correct order with override  
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_add(type='SEPARATE')
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_add(type='GOAL')
        #add goal object to goal brain setting below
        state = settings.boids.active_boid_state
        if (context.scene.spyderfy_tool.my_goalobject == True):
            state.active_boid_rule.object = bpy.data.objects['bugsystemgoal']
        bpy.ops.boid.rule_add(type='FLOCK')
```

To find this answer I had to take a look on some changes that happened to blender python commit, that you can see on this link, line 454
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/ac263a9bce53e190d07d679a058a230e91e722be